# VSCode debugger attach to local process

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, attach-to-process

One of the great features of PyCharm is that it allows its debugger to attach to python processes running locally (and outside of the IDE).

As I am trying to move to VSCode to work in Python, I am struggling to configure **launch.json** to simulate PyCharm's attach to local process feature.

```
{
    "name": "Python: Attach",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "attach",
    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "remoteRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "port": 8001,
    "secret": "my_secret",
    "host": "localhost"
},
```

This configuration is created by default when I select **Python: attach** option for debugger but I am convinced this is for remote debugging (with port and all), and most Google search results just talk about remote debugging for Python with VSCode.

Anyone had success in attaching a local debugger or two to multiple python processes running locally?

Comment: hi, did you find out how to get it working?

Comment: @gab Unfortunately no. I ended up just creating a run configuration and running it in pycharm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that VSCode may have added this feature since the last answer was posted.

In the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) under "Basic Debugging", they explain the process:

> The simplest way to begin debugging a Python file is to use the Run view and click the Run and Debug button. When no configuration has been previously set, you will be presented with a list of debugging options. Select the appropriate option to quickly begin debugging your code.
>
> Two common options are to use the Python File configuration to run the currently open Python file or to use the Attach using Process ID configuration to attach the debugger to a process that is already running.

So in your case, you'd select the "*Run*" tab on the left, then "*Run and Debug*". You'll be prompted to "Select a debug configuration". Since you are trying to attach to an existing/already running script, select "*Attach using Process ID*". Then select the Python thread you would like to attach to.

I just tried this on my machine (VS Code version 1.45.0 and Python Extension version 2020.4.76186) and was able to attach to a running process.

Answer (score 10):

Local attach is currently not supported but is being worked on.

Comment: Github issue tracking this: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1078

Comment: As of January, 2020 an experimental mode to do this is enabled: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1078#issuecomment-575271797