# Debugging Python in VSCodium with “Attach using Process ID” times out on macOS Catalina

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to attach VSCodium (basically VSCode without MS’s tracking) to a running process, but keep getting a “Timed out waiting for debug server to connect” error message. The logs within `~/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.8.105369` aren’t any more informative.

[The documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_basic-debugging) looks like it should just work, and [it has worked for others before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61719143/1913230). Has something changed in macOS Catalina (10.15.7), maybe a permissions thing? Or am I missing something else entirely?

This is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Attach using Process Id",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "logToFile": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Tried [doing the same in PyCharm CE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/attaching-to-local-process.html), where I get “Connection to Python debugger failed: Accept timed out”, so even more probable that it’s a macOS thing, right?

Comment: -Have you tried this process in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what I did back then, but right now this just works:

1. Add the following to the code:

   ```py
   import debugpy
   debugpy.listen(5678)
   debugpy.wait_for_client()
   debugpy.breakpoint()
   ```
2. Run it
3. Use VSCodium’s “Attach using Process Id” and search for the running code