# possible to re-connect to a running python debugger after re-connecting to a remote vscode dev container?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote-ssh

##### Current behavior (issue):

1. I was debugging on spotty wifi and lost my ssh connection the remote dev container.
2. After the connection was re-established, I reloaded the window to my remote dev container and my debugger was gone.
3. I also noticed that an `htop` was still running in a gnu screen session I had created in the remote container before I lost connection to it

##### Desired behavior:

Here is an example of the behavior that I'm looking for:

1. connect to remote dev container
2. launch a debugger that starts running through a python script
3. suppose eta to "break point A" is ~5min
4. uh-oh our wifi just dropped, battery died, etc
5. connection re-established after 10min
6. dialog pops in vscode "Reload Window", click "Ok"
7. window reloads and debugger re-appears, paused at "break point A"

##### Open questions (for me):

Is it possible to have a python debugger that is running in a remote linux dev container 'persist', so that upon re-connecting to the dev container, you can 're-connect' to the debugger?  I feel like this should be possible, since for example, its possible to re-connect to remote containers and have stuff that persists in gnu-screen sessions.

##### Some possible solutions (documentation):

1. the docs discuss something called ["[debugging] process id"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_additional-configurations) that you can have the debugger connect to, assuming this is just a normal linux process it should persist just fine inside eg a screen session.  the question is: how do you convert "Python file" launch configuration to something like a "process" that you can connect to later and would "later" need to be a different launch config?
2. [this issue talking about "local debugging processes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819908/vscode-debugger-attach-to-local-process), idk if this is what we want since the context is a remote dev container...